# Water pump stops after a few cycles

Tags: hardware

I have a small water pump (https://supermagneter.no/vannpumpe-6v-1-2l-min-tilkobling-4-mm-id625) that I control with a relay that is controlled by the raspberry pi. Usually I can start and stop the pump a few times, but then it suddenly stops moving. I can still here the relay switching but the pump doesn't move. If I switch the polarity over the pump, the pump runs again (in the opposite direction). When I switch back to the original polarity the pump runs again, for a few times before it wont run anymore.

Anyone have any idea what is causing this behavior? I was thinking that maybe there is a position of the rotor for the DC motor where no torque is being generated (or not enough) but that that seems like a very poorly designed motor.

I was planning to use this to water my plants over summer and with this intermittent behavior I am afraid they will die (sob)!

Comment: Sounds very much like a problem with the pump so not a pi issue

Comment: `If I switch the polarity` ... how do you do that?

Comment: remove the Raspberry Pi ... remove the relay ... connect the pump to its power supply by one wire ... connect a second wire to the power supply ... touch the second wire to the pump terminal ... remove wire ... wait for pump to stop ... touch wire again ... repeat ... does the pump still fail?

Comment: Yes, I see the same behavior with the power supply directly connected to the pump: it runs a few times then refuses to move until I change the polarity. I change the polarity simply by exchanging wires connected to the pump (I agree it is not a pi problem but running a water pump seems like a fairly common pi project so was hoping someone maybe had some input)

Comment: Is the pump just shoving into a closed tank? If so, pressure would build up, and that might be affecting something.  What does it do with no fluid load?

Comment: Same behavior with and without load. I have just been pumping in and out of two cups, so only atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert with pumps but I've seen such a behavior in the past.

The pump (pretty similar to this one) stopped working after a few (4-6) start/stop cycles with no apparent reason.
Back then there was nothing like the Pi, but here's how we troubleshot it:

- start the pump "forward" until it gets "stuck"
- switch polarity "backward"... gets stuck again!
- Remove everything and do the same tests with pump directly connected to power source... Same results.

We had only 1 pump (for a proof-of-concept) so we couldn't know if it was normal.
We took the phone and called the manufacturer... Turned out they had a faulty batch and we were unlucky enough to get one of these.

Again, I'm no expert but what you describe sounds strangely similar.

I'd suggest you get in touch with the reseller website or maybe directly with the manufacturer to get an exchange.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That does indeed seem very similar to what I experienced. I did get in touch with the reseller and they told me to ship it back, but in the meantime I think I managed to fix it, see answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone ends up here with the same issue, here is how I solved it (for now...)

I tried to poke a little at the rotor through a small opening in the side of the motor with a small screw driver. When I rotated the rotor a little bit the motor would run again but get stuck on the next stop.

When pushing the rotor around one full turn I could feel that at a certain angle the motion seemed jagged and with more friction. My guess is that when the motor decelerates after removing the power supply, it will have a high likelihood of getting stuck at this 'high friction angle' and not having enough torque get started when powering on (When powering the motor I could sometimes see the rotor move slightly but then getting stuck).

So I decided to remove the pump housing and with only the motor, it was running smoothly in both directions every time.

When I reassembled the pump housing it was still running smoothly every time in both directions (and still is, for now)!

My guess is that some part of the pump housing was mounted at an angle or too tightly which lead to this increased friction in some positions. When I opened it up and but it back together again this something (I could not see anything in particular) must have fallen into place.

This is strangely reminiscent of having to reboot the computer when everything seems to be stuck...

Anyhow, problem solved.